# Update and delete in one query based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am new to sql and I am still learning So any advice or help will be really appreciating. I am trying to delete a record where status is Completed, then update the column decrease number of particular column based on how many rows deleted. My table is below

```
tblA
    numberx             Address          Status
    0001                 AddA              New       
    0002                 AddA              Complete
    0003                 AddA              Not Done
    0001                 AddB              Complete
    0002                 AddB              Complete
    0003                 AddB              New
    0001                 AddC              Not done
```

I been able to do the delete  part but for the update query it is wrong it decreased every numberx in to 1 and giving me output like  which is wrong

```
tblA

numberx               Address        Status
0                     AddA            New       
1                     AddA            Not Done
0                     AddB            New
0                     AddC            Not done
```

I want it to be like this  if it is 0001 already and not yet completed will remail 0001

```
DELETE FROM  tblA WHERE STATUS = 'Complete';
UPDATE tblA SET numberx  = numberx  - 1;
SELECT * FROM tblA


Desired Output
numberx          Address         Status
0001               AddA           New       
0002               AddA           Not Done
0001               AddB           New
0001               AddC           Not done
```

Comment: Your delete query can delete multiple rows but in update you are just updating numberx=numberx-1. This may be issue

Comment: This is not a good table structure because your `numberx` values depend on other rows.  You should get rid of the `numberx` column, and if you need to number your results, do this in the queries or in the application instead.

Comment: Is numberx an auto_increment column or primary key? What sequence of events are allowed int status?

Comment: It is auto increment

Comment: If `numberx` is data type `INT` you cannot add leading zeros. Change it to `varchar` and remove auto increment.

Comment: it works for adding the leading 000 I really appreciate it

Comment: Copy everything which is not complete to another table(tblb), truncate tbla, insert everything from tblb to tbla, truncate or drop tblb.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`LPAD(str, len, padstr)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function.

> Returns the string `str`, left-padded with the string `padstr` to a length of `len` characters. If `str` is longer than `len`, the return value is shortened to `len` characters.

---

```
UPDATE tblA SET numberx  = LPAD((numberx - 1), 4, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type of the columns you are working with, if the initial value is 0 what will be the value after: 
UPDATE tblA SET numberx  = numberx  - 1; 
meaning you have to look at you primary keys and Identity rules also.